# Selenium Java how to return the driver back to the previous page

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have two links in pageA. when I click the 1st link it redirects to another page called pageB and do some certain jobs and returns back to pageA. From here it should again click to the 2nd link but instead it says page has reloaded and no cache available.

```
//List of all tickets
for(WebElement ticket: ticketList){
List<WebElement> ticketCells = ticket.findElements(By.tagName('td'));
  if(ticketCells.get(4).getText().equalIgnoreCase("Some Text")){
   ticketCells.get(2).click(); //Redirects to pageB
   .....
   do some job
   .......
   //Finally clicking on the 'SAVE & BACK' button which should return  to previous 
   //page and pick the 2nd ticket from the list of all tickets (1st for loop) 
   driver.findElement(By.id("save&back")).click();
  }
}
```

Here though it it is going back to previous page pageA but unable to pick the 2nd element from for loop for next operation.

Any thoughts on how to make it work.

Comment: did you need to navigate to the previous page in the same browser tab?

Comment: @santhoshkumar Yes, all these should happen to single browser tab.

Comment: driver.navigate().back(); will take you to the previous page

Comment: @santhoshkumar But at the end of 1st link operation I am clicking on 'Save & Back' button which itself redirect me back to pageA. How will the driver.navigate().back() will work when I am already returned to previous page.

Comment: Please add your code. And if possible link to the website.

Comment: @Shibankar I am not getting exactly what you are trying to achieve. Kindly add your code

Comment: @santhoshkumar Added few codes

Comment: while clicking on the ticket, hold the ctrl key and click so that it opens in a new tab. Use windows handles to switch to the tan then do the work then switch to the first tab. for holding down the crtl key you can use robot class

Comment: Don't add a link to the website like Guy said. It will change or vanish by time and make this question useless to others. Describe the page and the flow, possibly add screenshots or scribbles.

Comment: Note that the second interaction with `ticket` will _probably_ (you haven't mentioned an error message) fail with a `StaleElementReferenceException` since you've altered the page contents due to navigation. When navigating back (currently it's unclear whether this exception or the navigation is your problem) the elements in that list can't be interacted with. You have to select them again after navigating and use a counter variable instead of an iterator (determine there are N rows and count from 0..N-1 and do `ticketList.get(index)`). Please add the exception you get.

Comment: When you click on first link, your page is getting open in new browser tab, or it open's in same browser window? Provide more information on this issue and also provide your site `url`. So, we guys can help you easily.

Comment: @JainishKapadia Its open in the same browser.

Answer (score 3):

I think that what you want is the equivalent to press the ***Back*** button of your browser, right?

If its this, try that:

```
webDriver.navigate().back();
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to navigate to back or previous page in java selenium browser. You can try

```
webDriver.navigate().back();
```

If you want to navigate to back or previous page in python selenium browser. You can try

```
driver.back();
```

If you want to navigate to back or previous page in JavaScript selenium browser. You can try

```
driver.execute_script("window.history.go(-1)");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@try-catch-finally explained it very clearly. The below code is exactly what you need to handle the error.

for(int i = 0; i <2 ;i++){
ticketList = driver.findElements(selector);
ticket = ticketList.get(i);
List<WebElement> ticketCells = ticket.findElements(By.tagName('td'));
  if(ticketCells.get(4).getText().equalIgnoreCase("Some Text")){
   ticketCells.get(2).click(); //Redirects to pageB
   .....
   do some job
   .......
   //Finally clicking on the 'SAVE & BACK' button which should return  to previous 
   //page and pick the 2nd ticket from the list of all tickets (1st for loop) 
   driver.findElement(By.id("save&back")).click();
  }
}
```